# Response time of file_get_contents and valid xml

Tags: php, xml, rss-reader

I'm trying to read and store an RSS feed in my database using this method.

```
<?php
    $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.forbes.com/news/index.xml');
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($homepage,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r('$xml');
?>
```

But:

```
 1. How can  I check if `$homepage` contains a valid XML file or not?

2. I'm want to know how much time its taken to call if the url is valid XML file
```

`$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.forbes.com/news/index.xml');`

using try and catch exceptions..

Comment: @Brendan Long..thanks sir,to explain my requirements in correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$start = microtime(true);
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.forbes.com/news/index.xml');
$end = microtime(true);

$duration = $end - $start;

try {
    libxml_use_internal_errors() ;
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($homepage, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // error parsing XML
    throw $ex;
}
```

**Edit:** You can even combine the `file_get_contents()` call and `SimpleXMLElement` creation into one line using

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://www.forbes.com/news/index.xml',
    LIBXML_NOCDATA, true);
```

though any timing you wrap around that line will include HTTP retrieval *and* parsing

Comment: Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "<?xml version="1.0" ?> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/scripts/rss/rss_transformer.xsl"?>

Comment: sir, I got the time with this code but in next part I have this error which I mentioned above..

Comment: @omnath I can't replicate that error (PHP 5.3.6). What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @omnath Time to upgrade perhaps. Like I said, I get no errors with the above code. Are you sure you've copied it *exactly*?

Answer (score -1):

Below code will just works fine. Try it,

```
 $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.forbes.com/news/index.xml');
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($homepage,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
 echo  "<pre>";
 print_r($xml);
 echo  "</pre>";
```

Thanks.